# get group_concat distinct json_object of specific column

Tags: mysql, json, max, group-concat

Hi there I have the following code

```
SELECT modifiers.id,modifiers.name_ar,modifiers.name_en,
 CONCAT("[",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT(
   "id",       modifiers_items.id,
   "name_ar",  modifiers_items.name_ar,
   "name_en",  modifiers_items.name_en,
   "available",IF(product_modifiers.modifiers_item_id=modifiers_items.id,"true","false")
 )),"]") AS items 

FROM `modifiers` 
LEFT JOIN modifiers_items ON modifiers_items.modifier_id=modifiers.id 
LEFT JOIN product_modifiers ON product_modifiers.modifiers_id=modifiers.id  
WHERE modifiers.status<>'2' AND product_modifiers.product_id='1' 
GROUP BY `modifiers`.`id`
```

that returns

[image: picture]

need the same return except that `items` in the json in the picture does not repeated only get one and this one is the one has available= true

something like using

```
max(IF(product_modifiers.modifiers_item_id=modifiers_items.id,"true","false"))
```

but does not work

any help please ??

Comment: Why are you using `CONCAT()` to make a JSON array? Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

Comment: Yes that is possible what about my problem ?

Comment: I decided I couldn't figure this one out. Sorry.

Comment: You probably need nested queries, you can't put an aggregate function inside another aggregate.

Comment: Yes I know that